# My Ubuntu 20.04 machine crashes, monitor distorted

Tags: 20.04, freeze, visual-artifacts

When my Ubuntu machine crashes occasionally. It freezes and shows a distorted monitor screen. The only thing I can do is to restart the machine. I'd like to know how to prevent this from happening.

Ubuntu 20.04 64-bit, Motherboard: Foxconn AT-7000, Intel Core i7-3517U, Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2), memory 15.5 GB

The screen is distorted and the machine freezes or crashes.

[image: Screenshot]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ECAG5kOYOu8

Comment: An hardware problem, probably.

Comment: Video memory is shared. May be a memory problem. Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Thank you for the help. I have run memtest86 and got a FAIL test.

here is the copy of the report of the memtest86
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jl3Su4t3B02qd0p0le9EPteCreZAXQfD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please see Update #1 in my answer. Report back.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Is this a HP computer? If so, give me the model # for that. I'm having trouble finding the proper BIOS update for a Foxconn AT-7000. Is that the correct model #?

Comment: @heynnema its not HP, its a mini PC it's a NanoPC AT-7700 I just found its actual model on its very back with a very fine font size. The AT-7000 is printed on the motherboard but the actual version model is AT-7700.

https://linux-hardware.org/photos/computer/preview/215d42ee2200 

I also got the site for the BIOS update:

https://rebyte.me/en/foxconn/104582/file-374511/

Comment: @Harry I'm not sure that BIOS that you found is trustworthy. I'd keep looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Memory**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**BIOS**

Foxconn AT-7000 (NanoPC AT-7700)

You have a very old BIOS v4.6.5 from 11/28/2012. Research if there's a newer BIOS via the Internet. (I didn't easily find it). A newer BIOS could have an effect on `memtest` results.

**Update #1:**

`memtest` failed. You probably have a defective memory DIMM. You have two 8G DIMMS installed on your system. Carefully remove ONE DIMM and rerun `memtest` and then report back.

**Update #2:**

Reseating all DIMMS solved the problem.

Comment: I haven't been updated my BIOS, Yes and its hard to find one. But I performed update#1. I have removed one of the 8G DIMMS and run the memtest, it PASS. I also tried swapping the other DIMMS and to other sockets and all are PASS. Then I plug back both DIMMS and run the memtest gain and got a PASS.

Here are the 4 test result on the individual DIMMS and both DIMMS  
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ZmISkugU1Nipp9VAXBHWWp1StHc84Voj?usp=sharing

thanks in advance.

Comment: @Harry Then you probably had a DIMM that needed reseating.